# How to send video frames from flutter app to python flask server for facial recognition

Tags: python, flutter, flask, video-streaming, opencv

I had built a Flutter app that could send images to a Python flask. Now I am trying to do that with a video to get a real-time view of face recognition.

When we use the VideoCapture(0) feature of cv2, we get to see the rectangles on the recognized faces on a live video screen. Similarly, I want to get that on a Flutter app’s video camera where the faces recognized by the server would display a square on faces. How do I make this happen?